# Create a count consecutive variable based on the value in another column

Tags: r

Hi I have something like:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
               number=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1))
```

I want my 'want' to count the times 'number'=1 repeats per 'group'. Then I want the max number of times it repeats (want2). I want the 'want' to reset to 1 when 'number'=0:

```
dfwant<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
               number=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1),
               want=c(1,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2),
               want2=c(3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we want to reset when `number = 0`, we `group_by` `group` and create a new group whenever the number is 0. We then calculate `want` by taking `cumsum` of occurrence of 1 within each group and `want2` by taking `max` in group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group, group1 = cumsum(number == 0)) %>%
  mutate(want = cumsum(number == 1), 
         want = replace(want, number == 0, 1)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(want1 = max(want)) %>%
  select(-group1)

#   group number  want want1
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1      0     1     3
# 2     1      1     1     3
# 3     1      1     2     3
# 4     1      1     3     3
# 5     2      1     1     2
# 6     2      1     2     2
# 7     2      0     1     2
# 8     3      1     1     1
# 9     3      0     1     1
#10     3      1     1     1
#11     4      0     1     2
#12     4      1     1     2
#13     4      1     2     2
```

Comment: You could create an column `number ==0` and reuse it

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with `rleid` and `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(want = rowid(rleid(number)), want1 = max(want))
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   group [4]
#   group number  want want1
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1     1      0     1     3
# 2     1      1     1     3
# 3     1      1     2     3
# 4     1      1     3     3
# 5     2      1     1     2
# 6     2      1     2     2
# 7     2      0     1     2
# 8     3      1     1     1
# 9     3      0     1     1
#10     3      1     1     1
#11     4      0     1     2
#12     4      1     1     2
#13     4      1     2     2
```

---

Or using the `data.table` syntax

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, want := rowid(rleid(number)),.(group)][, want1 := max(want), group][]
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use `ave` for getting the `cumsum` per group like:

```
df$want  <- pmax(1, ave(df$number, df$group, cumsum(df$number==0), FUN=cumsum))
df$want2 <- ave(df$want, df$group, FUN=max)
identical(df, dfwant)
#[1] TRUE
```

To reset when `df$number==0` you can use `cumsum(df$number==0)` as an additional grouping, as already shown by @Ronak-Shah, for `ave`.

In case `df$number` holds also other values than `0` and `1` you have to use:

```
df$want  <- pmax(1, ave(df$number==1, df$group, cumsum(df$number==0)
    , FUN=cumsum))
```